# Mysql database name

Tags: mysql

My Mysql version is `Server version: 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)`
I have two databases, with a test table in each database. I can run the following select statement in one db, but not the other.

This works:

```
mysql> select * from 1ce62e96db1c4f6cb45535830366beb5.test;
Empty set (0.29 sec)
```

However, the other doesn't work:

```
mysql> select * from 344e2a0e00ca4fdf9998001885081798.test;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '344e2a0e00ca4fdf9998001885081798.test' at line 1
mysql> select * from `344e2a0e00ca4fdf9998001885081798`.test;
Empty set (0.31 sec)
```

So, it seems Mysql likes the database name `1ce62e96db1c4f6cb45535830366beb5`, but it doesn't like `344e2a0e00ca4fdf9998001885081798`.

Comment: I think the `344e2a0e00ca4fdf9998001885081798` is converted to the number `344e2` (i.e. `344 * 10^2 = 34400`)

Comment: I have no idea/explanation why the other db name isn't converted to `1` though. So my above comments may not explain well the reason of this failure.